# Django/Jquery problem - Cannot assign "u'Agua'": "Venta.producto" must be a "Producto" instance

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, autocomplete, foreign-keys

I'm using django+jquery autocomplete widget in my application. I customized the admin form of one of my tables to get autocomplete in the input textbox. 
It's working except that when I save the form the following exception occurs:

```
ValueError at /admin/Stock/venta/add/
Cannot assign "u'Agua'": "Venta.producto" must be a "Producto" instance.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/Stock/venta/add/
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "u'Agua'": "Venta.producto" must be a "Producto" instance.
Exception Location: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 273
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.5
...
```

It seems that it's not converting my autocompleted text in a Producto object. I saw the POST and it's sending the numerical key (i.e: 2) of the Producto selected. When I disabled all the autocomplete stuff, the post is exactly the same but it works. So something of admin.py or models.py sourcecode is wrong. Then something is doing that in a case it's converting it to an object and not in the other one.

The following is the **models.py** part:

```
class Producto(models.Model):
        detalle = models.CharField('Detalle', max_length=200)
        importe = models.FloatField('Importe')
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.detalle

class Empleado(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=100)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.nombre

class Venta(models.Model):
        importe = models.FloatField('Importe')
        producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
        responsable = models.ForeignKey(Empleado)
        mesa = models.IntegerField()
```

The following is the **admin.py** part:

```
class VentaAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        importe = forms.DecimalField()
        producto = forms.CharField()
        responsable = forms.CharField()
        mesa = forms.IntegerField()
        class Meta:
                model = Venta
                fields = ['producto', 'importe', 'responsable', 'mesa']

class VentaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form = VentaAdminForm

admin.site.register(Venta, VentaAdmin)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def search(request):
   results = []
   if request.method != "GET":
      return HttpResponse()

   term = q = None
   if request.GET.has_key(u'q'):
      q = request.GET[u'q']
   if request.GET.has_key(u'term'):
      term = request.GET[u'term']
   if not q or not term:
      return HttpResponse()

   if q == 'producto':
      model_results = Producto.objects.filter(detalle__contains=term)
      for x in model_results:
         results.append({'label': x.detalle,'value': x.detalle, 'id': x.id })
   elif q == 'responsable':
      model_results = Empleado.objects.filter(nombre__contains=term)
      for x in model_results:
         results.append({'label': x.nombre,'value': x.nombre, 'id': x.id })
   else:
         raise Exception("Unknown query_object")
   json = simplejson.dumps(results)
   return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

The javascript part:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $( "#id_producto" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/search/?q=producto",
        });
        $( "#id_responsable" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/search/?q=responsable",
        });
});
</script>
```

When a write, i.e.: agua, in the autocomplete textbox, it send a GET and the response is the following.

**http://127.0.0.1:8080/search/?q=producto&term=agua**

```
[{"id": 3, "value": "Agua", "label": "Agua"}]
```

**versions**

```
django 1.1.1
jquery 1.5.1
jquery-ui 1.8.13
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Agua" is the value thats being passed in back to your controller whereas Rails is expecting you to pass "3". Can you try changing your backend to send

```
[{"value": "3", "label": "Agua"}]
```

and see if it works

Comment: Rails? It's _Python_ not _Ruby_. Anyway, it doesn't work, if the number (primary key) is in the _value_, it appears in the combobox dropdown (1..2..3..4 one below of other), but when you select one, the text, i.e. _Agua_ appears in the textbox. Then the _value_ is for the options in the combobox, and the label is for selection, but if I modified it to reply _"value": "Agua", "label": 2,..."_, in the dropbox appear Agua, but when I select one, appear the numbre (primarykey) in the selection textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
```

In your Venta model definition, you defined producto as a foreignkey, that means, when you save the form, django **expects** to get the id of the related object (in this situation, id of the related *producto* record) not the label of the record.

Django uses a combo box for such foreignkeys, with an html output like:

```
<select name='producto'>
    <option value='3'>Agua</option>
    ...
```

If you sdisplay that field as a **raw_id_field** ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)), django will display **id** of the object, and write the unicode value near the field.

So you have to pass **the id of the relatred object**, not the name or unicode string. I dont use autocomplete widget, but there must be a proper way to do it correctly.